# How to run ngrok and apache/nginx on same server?

Tags: apache, nginx, web, port, ngrok

ngrok use port 80, apache or nginx use port 80 too. I want run ngrok and web in one server and use port 80 and use sub domain to distinguish them.

e.g. ngrok running at tunnel.mysite.com and nginx's web running at web.mysite.com

How to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have both listening on the same port.

You could change the port for `ngrok` (e.g. to 8080) and then setup a new virtual host in `nginx` to reverse proxy http://tunnel.mysite.com to http://ngrok:8080.

Example nginx config:

```
server {
    server_name web.mysite.com;
    ...
    }
}

server {
    server_name tunnel.mysite.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://ngrok_IP:8080;     
    }
}
```

Comment: I need something similar to that, I need run ngrok and call the nginx locations URLs via ngrok domain name, can you help on that?